# Rounded corner div in IE(6/7)

Tags: css, internet-explorer, html, rounded-corners

Here's the code for rounded div. Everything works fine except IE(6/7), even in IE(8/9) it's pretty good, and obviously other browsers seem nice on the rounded div. Described later after the code.

**html code:**

```
<div id="tweets">
    <div id="tweets_text">
        <div id="tweets_text_top">
            <div id="tweets_top_left">
            </div><!--#tweets_text_left-->                          
            <div id="tweets_top_right">
            </div><!--#tweets_text_right-->
        </div><!--#tweets_text_top-->                       
        <div id="tweets_text_middle">
            TeXt HeRe....
        </div><!--#tweets_middle-->                     
        <div id="tweets_text_bottom">
            <div id="tweets_bottom_left">
            </div><!--#tweets_text_left-->                          
            <div id="tweets_bottom_right">
            </div><!--#tweets_text_right-->
        </div><!--#tweets_text_bottom-->                    
    </div><!--#tweets_text-->               
</div><!--#tweets-->
```

**css code:**

```
#tweets{
    clear: both;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    padding: 0px;
    border: 0px;
}
#tweets_text{
    width:214px;    
    clear: both;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    border: 0px;
    background: #141414;
}
#tweets_text_top, #tweets_text_bottom{
    width: 214px;
    height: 10px;
    background: #000000;    
    clear: both;    
}
#tweets_top_left{
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
    background: url('images/top_left.jpg') no-repeat;   
    float: left;
    clear: left;
}
#tweets_top_right{
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
    background: url('images/top_right.jpg') no-repeat;
    float: right;
    clear: right;
}
#tweets_bottom_left{
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
    background: url('images/bottom_left.jpg') no-repeat;
    float: left;
    clear: left;
}
#tweets_bottom_right{
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
    background: url('images/bottom_right.jpg') no-repeat;
    float: right;
    clear: right;   
}
#tweets_text_middle{    
    width: 200px;
    padding: 7px;
    background: #000000;
    color: #f4f4f4;
    font-size: 12px;    
}
```

The images are here:
[rounded div's images](https://docs.google.com/leaf?id=0BzJd2t38NclBYWUyM2E5YTAtYTRkNi00MWM4LTg4NWQtZmI0YmE2YmMwOWE4&hl=en)

Now it occurs only in IE(6/7). The bottom portion isn't rounded like the top portion. If you test, hope you will find what I asked for.
If any one can find the mistake I will be grateful.

If you have any problem to understand or to get the docs, let me know.

Thanks.

Comment: Which DocType are you using? If you don't know, then that's likely the issue.

Comment: I know this not might resolve the issues with your code above, just FYI have you tried this http://css3pie.com/ You can use css3 code for making your round corner, with IE

Comment: I fixed your code formatting after you'd edited, think I got the edit right too but feel free to roll back if you think it's wrong

Comment: @Diodeus heres the doc type:
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
@omabena I knew the css3 rounded properties. Thanks though.
@Drackir & @clairesuzy thanks for the editin.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a very popular jQuery round corner plugin.

### http://jquery.malsup.com/corner/

It's supported in all browsers including IE6. It draws corners in IE using nested divs (not images). It also has native border-radius rounding in browsers that support it (Opera 10.5+, Firefox, Safari, and Chrome). So in those browsers the plugin simply sets a css property instead.

### Here's How to use it

You need to include the jQuery and the Corner js script before `</body>`. Then write your jQuery like $('div, p').corner('10px'); and place before ''. So your html will look like the below code. Here i'm making round corners for all `div` and `p` tags. If you want to do it for specific id or class then you can do something like `$('#myid').corner();`

```
<body>
    <div class="x"></div>
    <p class="y"></p>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://github.com/malsup/corner/raw/master/jquery.corner.js?v2.11"></script>
    <script>$('div, p').corner();</script>
</body>
```

### Check working example at http://jsfiddle.net/VLPpk/1

Comment: Thanks @Hussein.
But what if i switch off the javascript on my browser!!!
not sure... will it work or not!!!!!!
i just tried to make the rounded corner with images..Thats why i post the thread.
But again thanks for the useful jquery link and u r quick replay.

Comment: Why would you switch javascript off. Every site on the web have some type of javascript, don't worry about 1% of people who have JavaScript disabled for whatever reason.

Comment: No no, i just gave u the example. I worked with some guys, some of them does so. its rare i know but still 1% is there.

actually i just wanted to test the rounded corner. its worked fine except the ie(6/7). so i thought i made some mistake and cant find it out.

Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

This is an excellent tool for cross-browser rounding corners: http://css3pie.com/

It's specifically made to handle IE6-8 which doesn't support any css corner rounding.

Answer (score -6):

Use the code in CSS to round.

```
border-radius:7px 7px 7px 7px;
```

Comment: So how exactly does this solve anything?  Any IE version below 9 does not support `border-radius`.

Comment: -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
hope it will work.

Comment: Liza5757, you really don't understand what you're doing.  `-webkit-` is just for older Webkit browsers like Safari and `-moz-` is just for older Mozilla browsers like Firefox.  The OP is only having problems with **INTERNET EXPLORER 6 & 7**, where rounded corners are **NOT** possible using your CSS, or any CSS at all.  In other words, your answer is not applicable to his question... not even a little bit.